# Ubuntu 16.04.1 has appeared as .rar file. How do I burn it to a disk to use to install Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, dvd

I am interested in using Ubuntu for the fist time, so I went to the Ubuntu download page (https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), to get the download file. When the file downloaded he file, it appeared in WinRAR, so I cannot burn the file to a DVD. Can anybody point me in the right direction as to how to burn this file to a DVD when the file appears as a WinRAR file? Any help would be great appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: WinRAR usually associates itself with .ISO files and you probably don't have enabled the option that shows the common file extensions in Windows (the way to enable it is different on most Windows versions, so I can't tell you how to do it without knowing your current OS version). So in theory you should be able to burn the file without a problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's not actually a RAR file, it's just that WinRAR wants to open ISOs.

**This happens when both of these two conditions are true:**

1. Windows is configured to *Hide extensions for known file types*, which is the default.

   [image]
2. WinRAR is installed, and configured to open ISO images.

   [image]
   Open WinRAR, and Click `Options > Settings > Integration` untick the ISO box, as shown above.

---

**Next,**

Right-click on the downloaded file, and in the context menu go `Open With > Windows Disc Image Burner.`

[image]

Insert a blank DVD, choose to verify the image after burning, and hit burn.

Done! :)

Comment: When I try to 'open with' there is no option to open with 'Windows disc image burner'

Comment: @R.McEvoy - Alright, can you please search for "File Extensions" in the start menu, and there should be a link to turn "hide file extensions for known file types" off.

Comment: I turned this off and tried again but still not getting the option (I'm using Windows 10)

Comment: @R.McEvoy - What is the extension of the file showing as now that you've enabled showing it?

Comment: @R.McEvoy - Please see edited answer.

Comment: I solved the issue. I turned off the WinRAR option, then inserted the blank DVD. Windows asked how I wanted to use the DVD, I chose the USB drive option, then I dragged the file (that as a result of the setting change in WinRAR ended in .iso) onto the disk to be burned. I'm now going to try to install Ubuntu on a another PC, although, the PC only has 1.2GB of RAM, so I need to replace the 256MB stick with a 1GB stick in order to meet the hardware requirements. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @R.McEvoy - If you did that, then I'm afraid you didn't burn it correctly. Burning an ISO onto a data DVD is **not** the same as burning an ISO directly to a DVD. The only way to burn it correctly is to use Windows Disc Image Burner as a described above.

Comment: @R.McEvoy - If there still isn't an option for that, do right-click, `Open With -> Other application -> select c:\windows\system32\isoburn.exe`

Answer (score 0):

Try: do right click on downloaded iso, open with appropriate cd burner app

or

You can do that from pendrive too , download rufus portable app from [rufus.akeo.ie](http://rufus.akeo.ie) , attach pendrive a, open this app and select your downloaded iso file.